# Access page element popup from another window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Open a url from base page open.php  using

```
window.location("open1.php");
```

in a pop up window

Now I opened another popup on click a button on open1.php using

```
window.location("open2.php");
```

in a now pop up window

Now I want to access the elements of open.php from open2.php using javascript .Something like:

```
opener.document.getElementById("#any_element_id_on_open.php");
```

How can I do So?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `opener.opener`.

**open.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">Hello world.</div>
    <script>
        open("open1.php");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**open1.php**

```
<html>
    <script>
        open("open2.php");
    </script>
</html>
```

**open2.php**

```
<html>
    <script>
        alert( opener.opener.document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText );
    </script>
</html>
```